Wireshark BGP Decoding
I have a question about how Wireshark decode MP_REACH_NLRI BGP-attribute witj AFI = 1 and SAFI = 128. On the screenshot prefix length is 118 bits. We have 24 bits for one MPLS label and 64 bits for Route Distinguisher. 118 - 24 - 64 = 30. So we have 30 bits for IPv4 address, not 32. Why there is no /30 mask appended to IPv4 address in Wireshark for this field? Or did I misunderstand something in RFC?  In RFC 8277 I have found "In an MP_REACH_NLRI attribute whose SAFI is 128, the prefix will be 96 bits or less if the AFI is 1 and will be 192 bits or less if the AFI is 2". Why we have there "96 bits or less"? Isn't it controversary with real trafic?

I think the confusion is that, in RFC 4760 §3 and RFC 8277 §2.3 the maximum encoded length of each single NLRI, excluding the next-hop information which has a length dependent on the AFI/SAFI.
Wireshark appears to be displaying the length of the next-hop (label stack) plus the length of the NLRI.  The RFC is just writing about the max length of NLRI itself (RD+prefix).
In VPNv4 the length isn't even encoded anywhere in the BGP message or calculable only from various length fields -- you have to parse the MPLS labels (for the S-bit) to consume all the next-hop information, and the NLRIs are found after that.
RFC 8277 actually calls this out explicitly in the aforementioned section:


S:
In all labels except the last (i.e., in all labels except the one
immediately preceding the prefix), the S bit MUST be 0.  In the
last label, the S bit MUST be 1.
Note that failure to set the S bit in the last label will make it
impossible to parse the NLRI correctly.  See Section 3, paragraph
j of [RFC7606] for a discussion of error handling when the NLRI
cannot be parsed.




Thank you for the answer. Seems a bit strange for me that RFC doesn't include MPLS labels in the length in the sentence I have mentioned which caused a bit of confusion for me. "In VPNv4 the length isn't even encoded anywhere in the BGP." - But how will we find the length of the prefix if there are miltiple of the,?

For a /32 IPv4 prefix, the length of a VPN_IPv4 prefix would be 96.
RD (64) + IP (32) = 96 bits
For other masks, it would be lesser.
For the above case:
64 (RD) + IP (30) + 24 = 118 bits
where, 24 = an MPLS Label [20] + Reserved [3] + Stack bit[1]
This means the last two bits aren't part of prefix i.e. they are zeroes representing a /30.
Regards.

Thank you for the answer. Yes, I understand that it must be /30 prefix, but why doesn't wireshark display it? Do i misunderstand something or is it really missing in wireshark decoder?

The output seems to closely resemble whats in the packet. It would be friendlier to display the mask explicitly.
